# Check for value changes in variable

Tags: angular

I have 2 components in my angular app. Component A is a header and component B sets a value that I need in component A. The problem is that component A is getting set before B so the value that I need is not being displayed when I need it. If I refresh my browser then it shows. My code will explain better.

Component A

```
  offerExpiry: any;

  constructor(
    public expiry: ExploreOfferService
  ) {

  }
  ngOnChanges() {
    this.expiry.event.subscribe((data) => {
      this.offerExpiry = data;
    });
  }

  <div class="col-5 right">
    <div>
      <span *ngIf="offerExpiry">{{offerExpiry?.data}} days left to respond</span>
      <img src="../../../../assets/icons/calendar(old).png">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Component B

```
offerExpiry: any;

...

  async ngOnInit() {
    if (this._exploreService.offer) {
      ...
    } else {
      const offer = await this._exploreService.getOfferDetails();
      const date1 = new Date(offer.expiryDate);
      const date2 = new Date(offer.startDate);
      const diffTime = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
      const diffDays = Math.ceil(diffTime / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
      this.offerExpiry = diffDays;
      this._exploreService.publishExpiryDate({data: this.offerExpiry});
    }
  }
```

service file

```
  public publishExpiryDate(data: any) {
    this._subject.next(data);
  }
```

Comment: Why async  is used in component B? Please post more code.

Comment: @PareshLomate I have added more code

Answer (score 2):

When you are getting data from service do this in your service: create a subject and a method to get it subscribed in component B

```
private com_sub = new Subject<any>();
getData(): Observable<any> {
   return this.com_sub.asObservable();
}
```

whenever you get data in from service, pass it to subject:

```
this.com_sub.next(data);
```

In Component B, that loads earlier, subscribes that subject like :

```
this.yourservice.getData().subscribe(data => {
  console.log('your data here',data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable of type any in your service file then need to assign it in behaviroural subscriber that will listen when your component B loaded and subscribe the variable in onInit() in component A.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnChanges` is life hook for component binding changes, rather than subscribing observable there, subscribe the service variable in constructor or `ngOnInit`

Service.ts

```
public getSubject() {
    return this._subject;
}

public publishExpiryDate(data: any) {
    this._subject.next(data);
}
```

In Component A,

```
constructor(service: Service) {
    this.service.getSubject().subscribe((data) => {
      this.offerExpiry = data;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create one shared Observable service in your module and once your values are set from component B update the value and subscibe that observable variable in component A. so you will be received you updated value

steps are as follows

step 1 : create shared observable service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ObservablesService { 

constructor(
) { }


public updatedValue = new BehaviorSubject<object>([]);
 changeInUpdatedValue(value = {}) {
    this.updatedValue.next(value);
 }
}
```

step 2 : Import that service in constructor and from Component B calls method changeInUpdatedValue function onces you receive the value

```
 constructor( 
    private _observablesService: ObservablesService,
) { 
   //in data you can send your updated value whatever it is array,object or string
  this._observablesService.changeInUpdatedValue({ status: true, data: {} });
}
```

step 3 : Import that service in constructor and from Component A subscribe method updatedValue function onces you receive the value

```
  constructor( 
    private _observablesService: ObservablesService,
) { 
  this._observablesService.updatedValue.subscribe((result: any) => {
     //you will receive your value here
  })
}
```

Thanks